# Spring Batch Job does not enter STOPPED state, application never exits

Tags: spring-batch

I have a Spring batch job that was created from [the documentation](https://spring.io/guides/gs/batch-processing/).

The application never exits. The Job is in the repository with STATUS=STOPPING, EXIT_CODE=COMPLETED.

I would expect the Job to have status of STOPPED. Is the appropriate way to exit application by adding a System.exit()?

I added logging in an afterJob() listener and it notes the status of the only Step as COMPLETED with an Step Exit Status of COMPLETED as well. Interestingly, the jobExecution also has a job status of COMPLETED, but the default logging from the SimpleJobLauncher afterwards logs a status of STOPPING.

Spring Batch starter 2.1.2.RELEASE

EDIT:

> [BatchJobCompletionNotificationListener] !!! JOB FINISHED!
>
> [BatchJobCompletionNotificationListener] Job no longer running with status [STOPPING] exit status [exitCode=COMPLETED;exitDescription=].
>
> [BatchJobCompletionNotificationListener] Step [step1] status [COMPLETED] exit status [exitCode=COMPLETED;exitDescription=].
>
> [SimpleJobLauncher] Job: [FlowJob: [name=myjob]] completed with the following parameters: [{run.id=62, -spring.config.location=application.yaml}] and the following status: [STOPPING]

That is the end of my logging.

Not sure if it should make a difference, but I'm using a JdbcPagingItemReader with a PagingQueryProvider (based on [this example](https://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/spring-framework/spring-batch-tutorial-reading-information-from-a-database/)

Answer (score 0):

Just tried the getting started guide with boot 2.1.2.RLEASE and it works as expected:

```
# mbenhassine @ localhost in /tmp [9:57:11]
$ git clone https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-batch-processing
Cloning into 'gs-batch-processing'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 1121, done.
remote: Total 1121 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 1121
Receiving objects: 100% (1121/1121), 448.58 KiB | 205.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (682/682), done.

# mbenhassine @ localhost in /tmp [9:57:35]
$ cd gs-batch-processing/complete

# mbenhassine @ localhost in /tmp/gs-batch-processing/complete on git:master o [9:57:45]
$ vim pom.xml

# mbenhassine @ localhost in /tmp/gs-batch-processing/complete on git:master x [9:58:16]
$ cat pom.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>gs-batch-processing</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.0</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.2.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-batch</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
            <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>


    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>

# mbenhassine @ localhost in /tmp/gs-batch-processing/complete on git:master x [9:58:22]
$ mvn clean package
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building gs-batch-processing 0.1.0
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:3.1.0:clean (default-clean) @ gs-batch-processing ---
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.1.0:resources (default-resources) @ gs-batch-processing ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO] Copying 2 resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.0:compile (default-compile) @ gs-batch-processing ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 5 source files to /private/tmp/gs-batch-processing/complete/target/classes
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.1.0:testResources (default-testResources) @ gs-batch-processing ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /private/tmp/gs-batch-processing/complete/src/test/resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.0:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ gs-batch-processing ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.1:test (default-test) @ gs-batch-processing ---
[INFO] No tests to run.
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:3.1.1:jar (default-jar) @ gs-batch-processing ---
[INFO] Building jar: /private/tmp/gs-batch-processing/complete/target/gs-batch-processing-0.1.0.jar
[INFO]
[INFO] --- spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.1.2.RELEASE:repackage (repackage) @ gs-batch-processing ---
[INFO] Replacing main artifact with repackaged archive
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 3.558 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-02-27T09:58:36+01:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 25M/94M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

# mbenhassine @ localhost in /tmp/gs-batch-processing/complete on git:master x [9:58:36]
$ java -jar target/gs-batch-processing-0.1.0.jar

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.1.2.RELEASE)

2019-02-27 09:58:47.669  INFO 85483 --- [           main] hello.Application                        : Starting Application v0.1.0 on localhost with PID 85483 (/private/tmp/gs-batch-processing/complete/target/gs-batch-processing-0.1.0.jar started by mbenhassine in /private/tmp/gs-batch-processing/complete)
2019-02-27 09:58:47.672  INFO 85483 --- [           main] hello.Application                        : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2019-02-27 09:58:48.491  INFO 85483 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2019-02-27 09:58:48.497  WARN 85483 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource  : Registered driver with driverClassName=org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver was not found, trying direct instantiation.
2019-02-27 09:58:48.781  INFO 85483 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase          : HikariPool-1 - Driver does not support get/set network timeout for connections. (feature not supported)
2019-02-27 09:58:48.785  INFO 85483 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2019-02-27 09:58:49.137  INFO 85483 --- [           main] o.s.b.c.r.s.JobRepositoryFactoryBean     : No database type set, using meta data indicating: HSQL
2019-02-27 09:58:49.298  INFO 85483 --- [           main] o.s.b.c.l.support.SimpleJobLauncher      : No TaskExecutor has been set, defaulting to synchronous executor.
2019-02-27 09:58:49.446  INFO 85483 --- [           main] hello.Application                        : Started Application in 2.117 seconds (JVM running for 2.528)
2019-02-27 09:58:49.448  INFO 85483 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.b.JobLauncherCommandLineRunner   : Running default command line with: []
2019-02-27 09:58:49.532  INFO 85483 --- [           main] o.s.b.c.l.support.SimpleJobLauncher      : Job: [FlowJob: [name=importUserJob]] launched with the following parameters: [{run.id=1}]
2019-02-27 09:58:49.559  INFO 85483 --- [           main] o.s.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler     : Executing step: [step1]
2019-02-27 09:58:49.646  INFO 85483 --- [           main] hello.PersonItemProcessor                : Converting (firstName: Jill, lastName: Doe) into (firstName: JILL, lastName: DOE)
2019-02-27 09:58:49.646  INFO 85483 --- [           main] hello.PersonItemProcessor                : Converting (firstName: Joe, lastName: Doe) into (firstName: JOE, lastName: DOE)
2019-02-27 09:58:49.646  INFO 85483 --- [           main] hello.PersonItemProcessor                : Converting (firstName: Justin, lastName: Doe) into (firstName: JUSTIN, lastName: DOE)
2019-02-27 09:58:49.646  INFO 85483 --- [           main] hello.PersonItemProcessor                : Converting (firstName: Jane, lastName: Doe) into (firstName: JANE, lastName: DOE)
2019-02-27 09:58:49.646  INFO 85483 --- [           main] hello.PersonItemProcessor                : Converting (firstName: John, lastName: Doe) into (firstName: JOHN, lastName: DOE)
2019-02-27 09:58:49.658  INFO 85483 --- [           main] hello.JobCompletionNotificationListener  : !!! JOB FINISHED! Time to verify the results
2019-02-27 09:58:49.661  INFO 85483 --- [           main] hello.JobCompletionNotificationListener  : Found <firstName: JILL, lastName: DOE> in the database.
2019-02-27 09:58:49.661  INFO 85483 --- [           main] hello.JobCompletionNotificationListener  : Found <firstName: JOE, lastName: DOE> in the database.
2019-02-27 09:58:49.661  INFO 85483 --- [           main] hello.JobCompletionNotificationListener  : Found <firstName: JUSTIN, lastName: DOE> in the database.
2019-02-27 09:58:49.661  INFO 85483 --- [           main] hello.JobCompletionNotificationListener  : Found <firstName: JANE, lastName: DOE> in the database.
2019-02-27 09:58:49.662  INFO 85483 --- [           main] hello.JobCompletionNotificationListener  : Found <firstName: JOHN, lastName: DOE> in the database.
2019-02-27 09:58:49.664  INFO 85483 --- [           main] o.s.b.c.l.support.SimpleJobLauncher      : Job: [FlowJob: [name=importUserJob]] completed with the following parameters: [{run.id=1}] and the following status: [COMPLETED]
2019-02-27 09:58:49.668  INFO 85483 --- [       Thread-1] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2019-02-27 09:58:49.673  INFO 85483 --- [       Thread-1] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.

# mbenhassine @ localhost in /tmp/gs-batch-processing/complete on git:master x [9:58:49]
$
```

> Is the appropriate way to exit application by adding a System.exit()?

No, you should gracefully shutdown your application to correctly release any resource and avoid resource leak.

Comment: Not sure if it should make a difference, but I'm using a JdbcPagingItemReader with a PagingQueryProvider (based on [this example](https://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/spring-framework/spring-batch-tutorial-reading-information-from-a-database/) and